# Unable to use grouped labels for dates in Syncfusion chart

Tags: flutter, syncfusion, syncfusion-chart

I am trying to create a chart like this that requires grouped labels for range of dates.
[image: Required Graph]

I have tried using multilevel labels but I am not able to customize their design to look like the requirement. The ideal solution for me would be to find a way to group the primary x-axis labels rather than using multilevel labels. Anyone please help me. Here is my code:

```
      SizedBox(
      height: 30.h,
      child: SfCartesianChart(
        onAxisLabelTapped: ((axisLabelTapArgs) => print(axisLabelTapArgs.value)),
        plotAreaBorderWidth: 0,
        primaryYAxis: ChartHelper.buildNumericYAxis(textTheme),
        primaryXAxis: ChartHelper.buildDateTimeXAxis(),
        enableAxisAnimation: true,
        zoomPanBehavior: ChartHelper.buildZoomPanBehavior(),
        series: <ChartSeries>[
          if (provider.showPainCurve) ChartHelper.buildPainCurve(),
          if (provider.showBleedingCurve) ChartHelper.buildBleedingCurve(),
        ],
      ),
    ),

      static DateTimeAxis buildDateTimeXAxis() {
return DateTimeAxis(

  axisLine: const AxisLine(width: 0),
  labelIntersectAction: AxisLabelIntersectAction.hide,
  enableAutoIntervalOnZooming: false,
  interval: 1,
  autoScrollingMode: AutoScrollingMode.end,
  isVisible: true,
  autoScrollingDelta: 20,
  autoScrollingDeltaType: DateTimeIntervalType.days,
  majorGridLines: const MajorGridLines(
    width: 0.5,
    color: Color(0xFFFFDBCE),
  ),
  majorTickLines: const MajorTickLines(size: 0, width: 0),
  labelStyle: const TextStyle(height: 0, color: Colors.transparent),
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

We understand that you need to group the x-axis labels of the multiple series based on your query and currently, there is no option to group the x-axis labels using the [DateTimeAxis](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/DateTimeAxis-class.html). However, you can group the x-axis labels of the multiple series by using the [arrangeByIndex](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/CategoryAxis/arrangeByIndex.html) property in the [Category Axis](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/CategoryAxis-class.html). The [Category Axis](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/CategoryAxis-class.html) is implemented based on indexing, so if the [arrangeByIndex](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/CategoryAxis/arrangeByIndex.html) property is enabled, the x-axis labels of the multiple series will be grouped together based on their indexes.

Shared the User Guide documentation and Sample Browser links below regarding the [arrangeByIndex](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/CategoryAxis/arrangeByIndex.html) in the Category Axis for your reference.

UG: https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/axis-types#indexed-category-axis.

SB: https://flutter.syncfusion.com/#/cartesian-charts/axis-types/category/arranged-by-index.